# How to get line numbers in gvim editor?

Tags: linux, unix, vim

In my Unix, I have to use `:set number` command in gvim to get line numbers everytime. Is there any way or command to edit .tcshrc and get the numbers permanently ?
If yes, please help me with the command.

Comment: In what way do you think `.tcshrc` is related to (g)vim?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc

Comment: Try [vi.se] (but check their rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.tcshrc` is meant to contain various customisations of your `tcsh` shell (and other shells use different files: `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.). Vim is not part of your shell so it uses its own configuration file: `~/.vimrc`, where you are supposed to put things like `set number`. If the file doesn't exist, create it.

I would suggest you set aside ~30 minutes of your time to follow `$ vimtutor`, which goes over this very subject among other basics.